# Java вызов WinApi функций или управление открытыми окнами чужих программ

Tags: java, winapi, jni

Здравствуйте!

Есть программа написанная на **JAVA(модуль запускаемый как надстройка одновременно со сторонним приложением).**

**Из этой java-программы (надстройки), необходимо менять заголовок окон сторонней программы.**

Я имею неплохие навыки программирования на java, но с подобными задачами еще не сталкивался.  Я знаю, что есть **JNI** и **JNA** и куча сторонних библиотек, но в этой области я пока не опытен.

Без проблем могу решить данную задачу на С++ или на Delphi.

Но **задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать изменение заголовка чужой программы средствами JAVA**.

Начальство очень  не хочет плодить в проекте  модули написанные не полностью на java *(если никак по-другому - смирятся)*.

Рассматриваю варианты по отлову handle, заголовков окна, по id-процесса, по классу окна...  Боже! да как угодно -главное чтобы работало!

С радостью приму от вас советы, ссылки, комментарии, и кусочки кода.

Было бы отлично, если кто-то поделится исходником подобной задачи.

Примеры с JNA ,  JNI  приму с радостью!

Comment: [Java Access Bridge](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-136191.html) уже смотрели?

Comment: @Igor, спасибо, почитаю...

Comment: прошу прощения, мне кажется я вас обманул. Access Bridge это скорее в другую сторону - из Windows в Java, а вам надо наоборот. Очевидно, без JNI/JNA не обойтись [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173926/how-can-i-read-the-window-title-with-jni-or-jna) и [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391439/getting-active-window-information-in-java) есть примеры чтения заголовка окна. Как я понял Windows API вы владеете, т.о. сможете исправить под ваши нужды.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov спасибо за JNI/JNA  примеры, я как раз пытаюсь с этой технологией разобраться...  я почитал интернеты, везде пишут, что на java, только через JNI можно окнами рулить под windows...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Конечно, JNA — это ваш выбор. Надо скачать две JAR-ки [здесь](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/#download), либо подключить через maven. Вот набросал пример:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public class SetWindowTitle {
    public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary
    {
         final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary ("user32", User32.class, 
                          W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
         HWND FindWindow(String className, String windowName);
         boolean SetWindowText(HWND hwnd, String newText);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Нужно два аргумента: имя окна (или класс) и новое имя");
            return;
        }
        HWND hwnd = User32.instance.FindWindow(args[0], null);
        if(hwnd == null) {
            hwnd = User32.instance.FindWindow(null, args[0]);
        }
        if(hwnd == null) {
            System.out.println("Окно не найдено");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Нашли окно: "+hwnd);
        boolean result = User32.instance.SetWindowText(hwnd, args[1]);
        System.out.println(result ? "Успешно" : "Упс");
    }
}
```

Компилировать:

```
javac -cp jna-4.1.0.jar;jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;. SetWindowTitle.java
```

Запускать

```
java -cp jna-4.1.0.jar;jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;. SetWindowTitle "old-title" "new-title"
```

JNA очень удобно работает. Вы просто объявляете в вашем интерфейсе методы с теми же именами, что в user32 и с совместимой сигнатурой. Внутри JNA создаёт Proxy-класс, который для каждого метода поищет соответствующий внутри user32.dll и преобразует нужным образом аргументы.