# Как инициализировать другие окна в java?

Tags: java, jframe

Что я имею ввиду?Например: я знаю что какое-то окно, назовем его x будет открыто к моменту запуска программы, и в этом окне допустим запрашивается пароль, могу ли я сделать программу которая введет пароль в строку окна х?

Comment: Кстати, а какой операционной системы идет речь?

Comment: Если это Windows, то [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437626/java-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-winapi-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc) есть похожое решение вашей проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Говорят можно использовать класс `java.awt.Robot`, с его помощью можно управлять клавиатурой и мышкой.

Небольшой пример, написать I BODY  в текстовом редакторе:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotExp {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {      

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            // Creates the delay of 5 sec so that you can open notepad before
            // Robot start writting

            robot.delay(5000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Исходник: http://javist.ru/kak-ispolzovat-robot-klassa-v-java/

Comment: А собственно как найти это поле с помощи java робота? Ведь для того чтобы набрать туда текст сначала надо навести курсор, потом кликнуть в это поле, потом надо будет набрать и только потом нажать Enter или кнопку "Залогиниться"

Comment: Спасибо за крутую инфу, но комент выше прав, я хотел чтото типо перебора пароля для windows сделать , чтобы я запустил с флэшки прогу а она перебрала пароли, но это потом а сейчас чтобы прога просто нашла нужное место куда написать пароль

Comment: к сожалению мои знания на этом уровне заканчиваются, добавлю последнее: если окно это веб, то можно попробовать использовать selemiun и подобные

Comment: Если это соседнее приложение, то тут надо как-то достать схему окна и уже из него вытаскивать названия полей, при этом их изначально надо узнать, чтобы найти поле пароля (фиг знает как автор его назвал)

Comment: Если у вас нет доступа к API программы, то тут безнадежно.